# Using JWT claims vs. storing data about user in a plain text cookie

Tags: cookies, jwt, claims-based-identity

Our intranet system stores user data once the user logs in simply using a cookie (UserID, Name, Role..)

I was learning about JWT and tokens today and wondering is there any advantage to using that over the current way?

It seems like something might be insecure storing plain text in cookies but I also read that other web sites cannot see those cookies..

So is there any strong reason to use JWT tokens instead ?

Comment: How are you validating the cookie content in server side? For example, could an authenticated user change his UserId or Role (just using browser inspector) to get access to unauthorized resources? Are you using SSL/TLS?

Comment: Validate? The server just reads the values from the cookie.. very simple.. That bad ? What tool would I use to try changing my values in my cookie (I am new to the job so I didn't do it this way but it does feel insecure)

Comment: Open chrome inspector (F12)-->application data-->cookies and now you can play with the values.

Comment: Interesting. Ill try that and see if I can hack the system. If so, then it is something I should mention to the programmers here maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie can not be accesed by a different domain that the one which created it. This restriction is called "same-origin" policy and is a security measure to protect the local data of the site, but it does not mean that your cookie is conveniently secured

Since you are not validating the cookie content in server side, for example a user could change his UserId or Role to get access to unauthorized resources.

JWT can help you because thencontent is signed with a secret key. Any alteration to the content will break the digital signature and the server will reject the token.

An alternative is to use server session and store this data on server. 
The drawback with respect to JWT is that it needs server storage.